# Is there any variable like BigInteger, but as floating point?

Tags: c++

I saw, that there are libraries, that offer data types like BigInterger, but I need one, that contains a variable type, that is "big" (means: that can handle very high values) but also I need the possibility to divide it by another high number, so it wouldn't work with BigInterger..

Comment: Would big *rational numbers* be enough?

Comment: I bet there is somewhere, but considering how big the range of `long double` is, I don't really see any reason why someone would need it in real life.

Comment: I need it in the case of the calculation of estimated duration of a brute force password attack. So I have to handle with huge numbers, that i divide from time to time, to get it in scales, like weeks and years.

Comment: How about using logarithms?

Comment: Are you sure you need floating point? Integers can be divided too. Maybe integer division is sufficient for your needs. If it isn't, multiply your units by 10. Maybe integer division is now sufficient for your needs. etc.

Comment: Alf is right. Since you need multiplication and division, use the log-domain instead. This transforms multiplications into additions, and division into subtraction. And you're never going to have an overflow in the log-domain.

Comment: You do realize that even a regular `double` goes up to 10^300 with enough precision to be accurate to the millisecond in the range of 10,000 years. I'd say that's perfectly acceptable for a time estimation

Comment: @JulianSchnabel Do your values really exceed 10^308? Converting those to days or years is pretty irrelevant (that's 10^300 years - not really any different in terms of scale). If you are sure that `double` (or `long double`) is not sufficient for your task, please add an explanation why you think so. "I have large numbers" is not a justification.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf All IEEE floating point numbers are rational numbers, that's all you'll ever get from mantissa + exponent representations.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Read up on [*rational numbers* in programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_data_type) (short explanation, they use two integers as representation), and please refrain from adding negative value comments that misguide the OP.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What part about this is misguiding? I am fully aware you can have a data type representing the quotient of two `BigInteger`s. While your question seems to imply that as a suggestion, it is weird to ask if it is "enough" when OP asked for big floating point numbers, which are a strict subset of "big rational numbers". That was my point. I'm unsure what you read from my response that prompted such a reply.

Comment: The conflation of (programming) rational numbers with floating point numbers, is misguiding. The conflation of the mathematical sense of rational number with the programming concept, is misguiding. At a guess you're coming from a math/academic background, with an idea that the terms are context-independent -- they're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more precision in your calculations, you can use this [library](https://www.ttmath.org/) for big nums. Its simple and easy to start and created in C++ with template classes.

```
#include <ttmath/ttmath.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
// Big<exponent, mantissa>
ttmath::Big<1,2> a,b,c;

    a = "1234.3323454";
    b = "3456.1234534";
    c = a*b;

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```